# Silverlight Video Player Template

Tags: silverlight, templates, media

I'm developing a silverlight media player, I've implemented all of the required tasks, Now I'm seeking for a nice video player template including the following items:

1. Play/Pause Button
2. Stop Button
3. Forward/Rewind Buttons
4. Mute/Unmute Button
5. Volumn Up/Down Button
6. Time Slider to let user seek to specified position
7. A Label to show elapsed/total time
8. FullScreen Mode
9. Auto-Hide in Full-Screen Mode

Any help would be greatly appreciated.